# Jquery.svg loading performance issues

Tags: jquery, html, svg

Using jQuery.svg, I'm trying to load a long list of SVG files dynamically into their corresponding drawers on a website. I am succeeding in loading them appropriately, however, when they are all loaded, any click on the site becomes delayed for at least 2 seconds.

When the svg.load function is removed, the website is very fast.

This is the jQuery:

```
function initFloorPlans(){
    $('.list-item', '#tab1').each(function(){
            var zoneID = $(this).attr('data-value');

            $(this).find('.svg-load').svg();
            svg = $(this).find('.svg-load').svg('get');
            var path = "svg/thumbs/"+zoneID+".svg";

             svg.load(path,{
                addTo: false,
                changeSize: true
            }); 
    });

}
```

And this is an HTML sample:

```
<div id="tab1">
    <div class="list-item" data-value="zone1-1">
        <div class="svg-load"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-value="zone1-2">
        <div class="svg-load"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-value="zone1-3">
        <div class="svg-load"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-value="zone1-4">
        <div class="svg-load"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-value="zone1-5">
        <div class="svg-load"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item" data-value="zone1-6">
        <div class="svg-load"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if the above is enough information for an informed answer, but if you see anything suspicious, or if you can recommend an area where I can begin to check my code, that would be much appreciated.

The filenames go (zone1-1.svg), (zone1-2.svg) etc.

specific question: If there are some lingering events going on, is there a particular success function that might clear things up?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you calling the function? Please include more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so per Joseph Casey's request, here's the function call:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    initFloorPlans();
});
```

as it turns out, the function itself was completely fine. The real issue was that the SVG files got corrupted, simply after I removed the whitespace surrounding each of them with adobe Illustrator (just used the artboards checkbox).

I'm not sure if this solution will apply to anyone facing this type of problem, however, it is worth considering the fact that the SVGs are corrupted.

I am loading a few hundred SVGs now with absolutely no issues.

Thanks!